# What does $\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{2+\frac{3}{{\vdots}}}}$ evaluate to?

Tags: real-analysis, continued-fractions, eulers-number-e

I was curious what does
$$\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{2+\cfrac{3}{3+\cfrac{4}{\vdots}}}}$$
evaluate to. Empirically, I observed that it equals approximately $0.5819767$, and a calculator found that this value agrees with $\frac{1}{e-1}$ to at least 8 places. Is $\frac{1}{e-1}$ the exact value of this continued fraction? If this is true, is this result new? And how could the equivalence be proved?

Comment: Great question, but it's a duplicate of [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/continued-fraction-for-frac1e-2). It does evaluate to $\frac{1}{e-1}$. Also see [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501623/continued-fraction-please-prove-frac1e-gamma-x1-1-x-frac1x1-fra)

Comment: I am not sure why your question is voted to be a duplicate of [the one evaluating $\dfrac{1}{\text{e}-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/continued-fraction-for-frac1e-2).  However, it is a duplicate of [the one involving the lower gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501623).  Observe that $$\gamma(1,1)=\int_0^1\,\exp(-t)\,\text{d}t=1-\frac{1}{\text{e}}\,.$$

Comment: Here is [my old blog posting](http://sos440.blogspot.com/2017/08/an-easy-exercise-on-continued-fractions.html) explaining how this continued fraction can be solved.

Comment: @Batominovski Is it possible to prove this equality using elementary algebra (at least extreme elementary algebra, school level) ?

Comment: @Elementary  I have absolutely no clue.  I am not very knowledgeable about continued fractions.  Sangchul Lee may be a better person for you to ask.

Comment: @SangchulLee Would you like to answer the question I asked Batominovski?

Comment: @Elementary, I am also not an expertise in continued fractions. Anyway, here is a solution based on the general theory: Let $$I_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n-1}e^t\,\mathrm{d}t.$$ Then $I_n$ satisfies the following recurrence relation: $$I_1=e-1,\qquad I_2=1,\qquad I_n=nI_{n+1}+(n+1)I_{n+2}.$$ Indeed, it follows from integrating both sides of $(t^n(1-t)e^t)'=nt^{n-1}e^t-nt^ne^t-t^{n+1}e^t$ from $0$ to $1$. So we have $$\frac{1}{e-1}=\frac{1}{I_1/I_2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad I_n/I_{n+1}=n+\frac{n+1}{I_{n+1}/I_{n+2}}.$$ Repeatedly applying this relation then proves the identity.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for explanation. By the way Is this "logic" correct? The number $e$ is not algebraic. For this reason, the algebraic way doesn't exist for to prove this continued fraction.?Can we say?

Comment: I suspect that you have a particular technique in your mind, such as finding the value of a *periodic* continued fraction by setting up a rational equation and solving for it. Then yes, because $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: @SangchulLee yes, That is what I mean...It is impossible to solve with a rational equation isn't it?  this is what I want to ask.. like we've solved $\sqrt 2$ continued fraction. So looking for algebraic methods is meaningless, right?

Comment: I suspect so. At least we cannot obtain the value $\frac{1}{e-1}$ algebraically over $\mathbb{Q}$, although I am not sure if we can rule out the possibility in which your continued fraction may be associated algebraically with other transcendental quantities by some slick method.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you.  Your comment is point shot.